# Вызов массива из другого класса

Tags: java, массивы

Где я делаю ошибку при вызове через get метод в другом классе для обработки массива?
Спасибо.

Первый класс -

```
public class Getmethoden {
    public int[] test = {1,2,3,7,6,5,4};

    public int[] getTest() {
        return test;
    }
    public void setTest(int[] test) {
        test = test;
    }
}
```

Второй класс -

```
public class Prüfung {

    private final int gesucht = 5;

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        Getmethoden.getTest();
        for(int i = 1; i < getTest.length;i++){
// немного кода
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: а что у вас не работает?

Comment: @Andrew Доступа не было к методу почему-то вообще)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
public void setTest(int[] test) {
    this.test = test;
}

public static void main(String[] args) {
  int[] getTest = (new Getmethoden()).getTest();
  for(int i = 0; i < getTest.length; i++) {
    // ...
  }
}
```

Comment: Просто огромнейшее спасибо ..Топ

Comment: Если вам дан исчерпывающий ответ, отметьте его как принятый. Старайтесь не отвечать фразой спасибо на исчерпывающий ответ