# Нужна корректировка кода "поиск по массиву"

Tags: java, массивы

Всем привет, в общем у меня такая проблема..
Мне нужно рассчитать наименьшее расстояние в массиве для двух String. Это у меня хорошо получается, если нет дублируемых стрингов в массиве, например

```
String[] arr = {"12","111", "trubask", "truba","111", "jopa", "moin"};
```

но если

```
   String[] arr = {"12","111", "trubask", "truba","111", "jopa", "moin", "111"};
```

тогда расстояние рассчитывается от 1 до последнего элемента, а нужно от 1 до 4.. Как это изменить?
Код

```
               for(int i = 0; i < arr.length; i++) {
                for (int j = i + 1; j < arr.length; j++) {
                    if(string1.equals(arr[i]) && string2.equals(arr[j])) {
                        wert1 = true;
                        wert2 = true;
                        pl1 = i;
                        pl2 = j;
                     }
                   }
                 }
              distance = pl2 - pl1;
```

Как ограничить подсчет до первого поля, которое хранит искомый элемент?

Comment: Вы вот здесь ничего не забыли сделать? https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/1098225/%d0%92%d1%8b%d0%b7%d0%be%d0%b2-%d0%bc%d0%b0%d1%81%d1%81%d0%b8%d0%b2%d0%b0-%d0%b8%d0%b7-%d0%b4%d1%80%d1%83%d0%b3%d0%be%d0%b3%d0%be-%d0%ba%d0%bb%d0%b0%d1%81%d1%81%d0%b0

Comment: @Igor Это те стринги, между которыми нужно было найти расстояние.. Я их еще до этого задал))

Comment: @Igor забыл, исправлено))

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
boolean found = false;
for (int i = 0; !found && i < arr.length; i++) {
  for (int j = i + 1; !found && j < arr.length; j++) {
    if (string1.equals(arr[i]) && string2.equals(arr[j])) {
      found = true;
      pl1 = i;
      pl2 = j;
    }
  }
}
if (found) {
  wert1 = true;
  wert2 = true;
  distance = pl2 - pl1; 
}
```